# Controlling animation from other widget

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to control an animation on a widget (`widget 2` in the pic) using gestures captured from another widget (`widget 1` in the pic) and I'm having trouble finding the right way to do that.

The approach I currently think about is having the `AnimationController` in a common parent. `widget 1` would, via callbacks, update the value of this controller in the parent. `widget 2` would receive that controller a a parameter and therefore the animation in `widget 2` would correspond to the values provided by the gestures in `widget 1`

[image]

Is that the right way to do it ? If not, what would be a better approach ?
Edit: After trying this method, I notice that an exception get thrown

```
Another exception was thrown: AnimationController.dispose() called more than once.
```

I suspect the `AnimationController` object to be reconstructed on rebuild causing the error. Any idea on how to do it to avoid that ?

Thanks ! :)

Comment: Sounds good to me. You might want to have a look at making `Widget2` inherit from [AnimatedWidget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AnimatedWidget-class.html) to make things easier.

Comment: you could also use [scoped_model](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scoped_model)

Comment: no, I'll use redux.  By using redux, it is possible that the animation in widget 2 can be controlled by widget 1of another mobile phone, i.e. something like multi-players on-line game.  let me know if you want a complete example.

Comment: @JordanDavies I edited my post to add the error I get with this method, any idea of what I could be doing wrong ? Also do you have an example of how to use `AnimatedWidget` in my case ?

Comment: post your code then

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full sample of what I think you're trying to achieve, using `AnimatedWidget`. Might not be the most efficient way to do it, but it works.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Test")),
        body: SafeArea(child: Parent()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentState createState() => _ParentState();
}

class _ParentState extends State<Parent> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this);
    _animation =
        Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 100).animate(_animationController);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _animationController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(child: Widget1(animation: _animation)),
        Widget2(onSliderChanged: (value) {
          _animationController.value = value / 100;
        }),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Widget1 extends AnimatedWidget {
  Widget1({Key key, @required Animation<double> animation})
      : super(key: key, listenable: animation);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Animation<double> animation = listenable;
    return Opacity(
      opacity: animation.value / 100,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          "Hi",
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 40.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Widget2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueChanged<double> onSliderChanged;

  const Widget2({Key key, this.onSliderChanged}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _Widget2State();
}

class _Widget2State extends State<Widget2> {
  double _value = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Slider(
      value: _value,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _value = value;
        });

        widget.onSliderChanged(value);
      },
    );
  }
}
```